# android buttons and seekbar look older

Tags: android, xml

working on an android app for class, which has a few image buttons and a seek bar, and on eclipse in the graphical layout of my main xml file the buttons and seek bar look like the newer stuff you see on jellybean or kit-kat, but then when i go to launch my app onto my phone its using like the old blocky square seek bar which is highlighted in yellow vs the one that is a straight line and a blue circle. and ideas what the issue is? my minSdkVersion is 16 and targetSdkVersion is 19 so its not like im developing for older sdks?

here is my xml if that helps anything:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/calm" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/camera"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="startCamera"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/draw"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sketchPic"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="sendPic"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:onClick="adjustContrast"
        android:max="0xff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED FROM READING AROUND**

I found that if i put this `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` above setContentView in the onCreate method it will do what i desire. I tried this a while ago but did not place it above the setContentView which is key for this to work.

Thanks for the help peeps!

Comment: Did you specify a theme in your manifest? If so, what is it?

Comment: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` because I wanted to get rid of the title bar, thats prob what messed it up huh?

Comment: Yup you need to inherit from a holo theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if i put this `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` above setContentView in the onCreate method it will do what i desire. I tried this a while ago but did not place it above the setContentView which is key for this to work.

that way i can keep `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in the manifest which keeps the current android ui!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with my old Motorola Defy phone. They never updated the android version beyond 2.3.6.

To get around this I used a check to see if the Android version on a device is pre-honeycomb.

```
/**
 * Check if version of Android running on device is earlier than Honeycomb  
 * @return    true if running earlier version of Android, otherwise false  
 */
public static boolean isPreHoneycomb() {
    return (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB);
}
```

If this returns true then I manually set the seek bar thumb using using the `AbsSeekBar.setThumb` method to a copy of the more recent scrubber thumb graphic resources, which placed in my apps drawable folders.

Check what version of Android is on your phone which is exhibiting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` instead.